# Como deixa imagem do plot responsiva ao grafico em matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
#---------------- Importações------------------------

!pip install cartopy
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LATITUDE_FORMATTER, LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

#------------------------------------------------------
#----------------Leitura do Arquivo--------------------

ds = xr.open_dataset("/content/drive/MyDrive/ArquivoDeTeste.nc")
nome= "Arquivo de Teste"

#------------------------------------------------------
#--------------Criar Figura / plotar-------------------


t=ds['temperatura']-273.15


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

img=t.mean(dim='time').plot(cmap=cmap,add_colorbar=False)

ax.set_title(f'- {nome}\n{ds.isel(time=10, lat=0,lon=0).time.values}', fontsize=20)
#ax.set_extent([-20,-29,-54,-40])


#--------------------------------------------------------
#------------------Linhas e Contornos--------------------


gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='black', alpha=1.0, linestyle='dotted', 
linewidth=0.50,  draw_labels=True)

gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False

gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

#-------------------------------------------
Imagem segue em Anexo
```

[image: Imagem do Problema]

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante você fazer um meshgrid da sua lon e lat, assim transformando em 2D.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset("/content/drive/MyDrive/ArquivoDeTeste.nc")

t=ds['temperatura']-273.15 #POSSUI 3 DIMENSOES


lat = ds.variables['latitude'] #POSSUI 1 DIMENSÕES
lon = ds.variables['longitude'] #POSSUI 1 DIMENSÕES

lon, lat=np.meshgrid(lon, lat) #POSSUI 2 DIMENSÕES
```

Agora pra plotar seria bom usar a função `contourf`

```
plt.contourf(lon, lat, temperatura[0,:]) #temperatura no tempo 0
```

Vc pode ajeitando o mapa mudando o cmap, levels...